# pro tools midi controller vertical edit window scrolling

Tags: pro-tools, midi, controller, edit

I know this could be very strange, but i'd like to assign a fader to my midi controller to scroll vertically my edit window.

Any ideas?

Comment: hi goplastic, as it stands we can't help you with this issue. please add more information about your setup. And have you checked the protools manual?

Comment: i have pro tools 10 and a midi controller. i usually scroll the view with the mouse scroll but i'd like to do this with a midi controller fader!